# writing on rfid-Tag and locking block using CoE with IO-Link Master (ifm al1330)

Tags: locking, rfid, plc, twincat, ethercat

i have got the following issues.
I want to Read/Write on a Rfid-Tag and lock this block afterwards.

I have the following hardware:

- AL1330, IFM Io-link Master https://www.ifm.com/mounting/80284123DE.pdf
- DTI513, IFM IO-Link Rfid-REader/Writer https://www.ifm.com/mounting/11458695DE.pdf
- Beckhoff, PLC CX5230
- Rfid-Tag, ICode Slix, https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SL2S2002_SL2S2102.pdf

I can read the Uid, can write and Read Data Bytes on the RFID.
I fail to lock the Block afterwards. I tried various ways with CoE Communication.

I divide the Problem into 3 steps:

Step 1:

- Craft the CMD responsible for the Lock on the Tag.

  - This is specified in the responsible Norm
    [image: Command]
  - this are the Flags

  [image: Flags]

  - This leads me for example to this Command

  [image: Command Lock]

Step2 : Calculating the CRC
-For the CRC in the Norm there is one Example (CRC Iso/IEC 13239)

[image: CRC]

- 0x22 0x20 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0xab 0x04 0xe0 0x0b
  this command shall lead to CRC BAE3.
  My Oscat Lib Block Basic.CRC_Gen with this Parameter returns this value

[image: Parameter]
[image: Result CRC]

- Same as http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
  [image: Calc CRC]
- With more testing, the crc calucaltions differ, and i do not know why and how,
  and which one is correct.

Edit:
- More testing and i recognized, the Oscat Library FB Basic.CRC_Gen
fills any Input, shorter than 4 bytes, with 0x00.
- there should be the workaround, to use addressed commands with the optional Uid.

Step3:

- Writing the Command with the appended CRC to Tag via CoE
  - i use the Beckhoff FBs to access CoE

[image: COE]

- I can acces the different IDs with Subids and get Results,
  so this works
- i found the IO-Acyclic Command, which i think is the right one, to issue commands to
  the tag
- the docu in the AL1330 shows this
  [image: Docu Acyclic COmmand]

I tried a lot of different stuff, but cannot make it happen.
Problem is, i am not sure, if the CMD is correct or not, the CRC is wrong or how to make the Acyclic Command to work.

I tried for days and found no solution.
So i would be very glad for tips and hints in the right direction.

Thanks

I hope i do not violate any rules

Comment: To narrow it down, perhaps somebody can help only with the CoE Communication.
Is this the right approach to write commands?
And specifically to the acyclic Command, how should the FB Tc2_Ethercat.Fb?EcCoESdoReadEx be used in this case.

Comment: After talking with IFM, with the IO-link Devices it is just not possible to use this Lock function, it is not implemented.

Should have asked the simple Questions first